# Узнать окончание воспроизведения MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

Как узнать, что *MediaPlayer* завершил проигрывать аудио и начать воспроизведение другого аудио?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте этот способ:

```
 mP.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //переключение песни
    }
});
```